# Chrome getUserMedia locally workaround available?

Tags: html, audio, audio-recording

in relation to question

[Chrome getUserMedia Not Requesting Permission Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/) and [WebRTC - Browser doesn't ask for mic access permission for local html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318319),

I have to run my file locally (in a workshop setting where wifi may fail)
but I do need audio recording. Other than running Chrome with --disable-web-security,
is there a way to have the user turn on/off a setting from within chrome ?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Would the wifi stop you connecting to a web server running on the same machine as the browser?

Comment: no, but unfortunately thats not an option, the app needs to be very easy to install, it's an app for kids < 14..