# web audio input doesnt exist in chrome's flags

Tags: audio

I am working on a project about speech recognition, but my html file cannot find microphone.I mean that when I click the button "start recognition " it should pop a bar for allow or deny access to the microphone, but it doesn't.I figure out that I should enable web audio input from chrome://flags, but in chrome://flags there is no option for web audio input.
what should I do?

please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Speech API</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #controls {
                text-align: center;
            }
            #start_button {
                font-size: 16pt;
            }
            #transcript {
                color: darkred;
                font-size: 16pt;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #instructions {
                color: darkblue;
                font-size: 14pt;
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="transcript">&nbsp;</div>
        <br>
        <div id="instructions">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="controls">
            <button id="start_button">Click to Start</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var finalTranscript = '';
            var recognizing = false;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                // check that your browser supports the API
                if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
                    alert("Sorry, your Browser does not support the Speech API");

                } else {
                    // Create the recognition object and define the event handlers

                    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                    recognition.continuous = true;         // keep processing input until stopped
                    recognition.interimResults = true;     // show interim results
                    recognition.lang = 'en-GB';           // specify the language

                    recognition.onstart = function() {
                        recognizing = true;
                        $('#instructions').html('Speak slowly and clearly');
                        $('#start_button').html('Click to Stop');
                    };

                    recognition.onerror = function(event) {
                        console.log("There was a recognition error...");
                    };

                    recognition.onend = function() {
                        recognizing = false;
                        $('#instructions').html('&nbsp;');
                    };

                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                        var interimTranscript = '';
                        // Assemble the transcript from the array of results
                        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
                            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                                finalTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
                                //me sunarthsh js na to kopseis kai na pareis tis lekseis kai na allazeis auta pou thes
                            } else {
                                //console.log("event.results[i][0].transcript: " + event.results[i][0].transcript);
                                //if (event.results[i][0].transcript == "equals") {
                                    //... = "=";
                                //}
                                //else if (... == "by") {
                                    //... = "*";
                                //}
                                //else if (... == "divide") {
                                    //... = "/";
                            //}
                                //else if (... == "square") {
                                    //... = "^2";
                                //}
                                interimTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log("interim:  " + interimTranscript);
                        console.log("final:    " + finalTranscript);

                        // update the page
                        if(finalTranscript.length > 0) {
                            $('#transcript').html(finalTranscript);
                            recognition.stop();
                            $('#start_button').html('Click to Start Again');
                            recognizing = false;
                        }
                    };

                    $("#start_button").click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        if (recognizing) {
                            recognition.stop();
                            $('#start_button').html('Click to Start Again');
                            recognizing = false;
                        } else {
                            finalTranscript = '';
                            // Request access to the User's microphone and Start recognizing voice input
                            recognition.start();
                            $('#instructions').html('Allow the browser to use your Microphone');
                            $('#start_button').html('waiting');
                            $('#transcript').html('&nbsp;');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show us the code you're using, and check your browser's JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: do you mean the code for speech recognition?

Comment: Whatever code runs when your user hits the "start recognition" button.

Comment: The code runs as it should have in my teacher's laptop.The problem is on microphone, which operates with skype ,demos and other applications, but not with the above code of speech recognition.I think that i should do something with chrome's flags and web audio input.But my problem is that there is no option for web audio input in Chrome's flags.

Comment: Do you get error messages in the console? Have you tried `alert()` calls throughout to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: it cannot start recognition,as it detects problem with microphone! for  this reason i am trying chrome's flags .i am trying to enable web audio input from chrome's flags ,but no web audio exists.

Comment: And when you say "it detects problem with microphone", what does that error message look like?

Comment: when i clicjk button "start recognition", it should pop up a bar on the top of the page, which would have two buttons, one for allow and one for deny access to microphone.in my pc it doesn't appear

Comment: it should looks like this demo:http://web-apprentice-demo.craic.com/tutorials?tutorial=37&demo=1

Comment: Have you actually looked in the JavaScript console? If audio were not enabled in your Chrome, the demo wouldn't work either. Please confirm that you've checked Chrome's developer tools for error messages.

Comment: how can i check chrome's developer tools for error messages?

Comment: The very first comment in this thread encouraged you to check them. You really need to learn how to do basic JavaScript debugging, especially if you'll be doing complex JS like speech recognition. Read https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: yes its ok,but my problem isn't in the code,but it has to do with chrome's settings

Comment: I doubt that, the API has been in Chrome since version 25 and doesn't require enabling.

Comment: SO,what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Well, your code brings up the microphone prompt when I put it on JSFiddle.net just fine.

Comment: yes,i tested.so what can i do?

Comment: Hang on. You tested it and it works for you. What's the problem?

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to fix the problem with microphone?i want to run it from my pc,not online

Answer (score 0):

You need that page to be served by a webserver, but it sounds like you're just trying to open the HTML file with your browser. Chrome will block access to the camera/microphone unless the page was served from a webserver. You can create a local server on your machine to serve the page using the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the folder with your html file. (assuming you're on a MacOS/linux system).

See this answer for more information
[WebRTC - Browser doesn't ask for mic access permission for local html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318319/webrtc-browser-doesnt-ask-for-mic-access-permission-for-local-html-file)