# Speech recognition not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I am trying to access the audio from chrome browser using javascript code below, but when I click the the button the `recognition.onresult` event is not firing in chrome browser, however when I access the online webpage that contains live demo of speech to text, its working fine in chrome browser please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  recognition.onresult = function(event)
  {
    if (event.results.length > 0) 
    {
       alert("Working");
    }
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input type="button" value="Click to Speak"onclick="recognition.start()">
</form>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? Also, are you using an external library? At the moment, the current version of Chrome requires a `webkit` prefix (`webkitSpeechRecognition()`); there's no unprefixed version.

Comment: I replaced ( SpeechRecognition() );  with prefix ( webkitSpeechRecognition() ); the error it give me is  "not-allowed"

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318319/webrtc-browser-doesnt-ask-for-mic-access-permission-for-local-html-file?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried on my computer and it works:

```js
$(function () {
  try {
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  } catch (e) {
    var recognition = Object;
  }
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.onresult = function (event) {
    var txtRec = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      txtRec += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
    $('#txtArea').val(txtRec);
  };
  $('#startRecognition').click(function () {
    $('#txtArea').focus();
    recognition.start();
  });
  $('#stopRecognition').click(function () {
    recognition.stop();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="startRecognition">Start Recognition</button>
<button id="stopRecognition">Stop Recognition</button>
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: No its not working on my chrome browser, its not firing recognition.start();

Comment: The chrome version installed on my PC is " Version 46.0.2490.86 m" with windows 10

Comment: @FaisalSajjad my computer runs Windows 8.1 and Chrome is version 47.0.2526.73 m

Comment: @gaemaf its giving me error "not-allowed", why its giving error not-allowed?

Comment: you need to give authorization whenever the browser ask you. This happened for me the first time I executed my script.

Comment: Thanks @gaemaf, its working now, actually I was running locally as file://, so that's why it was not working, I run it on localhost now its working.